# RESTful API list files with 'setFields()' modifier gives unexpected results

Tags: google-drive-android-api, google-drive-api

In an Android app, I'm trying to list files from the Drive, using the **RESTful API**.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

I have 332 (number is just for example) files in the Google Drive and I run the following code snippet (taken directly from the doc above), trying to list them:

```
  private com.google.api.services.drive.Drive _svc;
  ...
  Files.List rqst = _svc.files().list(); //.setFields("items(title, id)").setMaxResults(90); 
  do try {
    FileList list = rqst.execute();
    Log.i("TAG", "count: " + list.getItems().size());
    rqst.setPageToken(list.getNextPageToken());
  } catch (IOException e) { rqst.setPageToken(null); }
  while (rqst.getPageToken() != null && rqst.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

if I use plain request:

```
  _svc.files().list();
```

the loop produces paged results as expected, i.e. **100 + 100 + 100 + 32** files

Adding additional modifier:

```
  _svc.files().list().setFields("items(title, id)");
```

gives me only the first page of 100 results. The '*getNextPageToken()*' produces NULL, indicating no more data available.

Needles to say that using "*setMaxResults()*" modifier produces the same results. For instance, if I add '*setMaxResults(90)*',

```
_svc.files().list().setMaxResults(90);
```

produces 90+90+90+62 = 332 files, but

```
_svc.files().list().setMaxResults(90).setFields("items(title, id)");
```

yields only 90 files, with no more pages available.

I am assuming that I must be doing something wrong, since I find it unlikely that I would discover a bug never reported (after googling for hours) in an interface that has been
around for ages now.

Comment: See what happens if you get another page (even if the 'last' page was smaller than the page size.)

Comment: Did you notice that 'getNextPageToken()' returns null. The new 'rqst.execute()' without a token gets me the same initial set again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request the nextPageToken as one of the fields you want to receive.  Otherwise, it will appear to be null since its not included in the response.

Comment: Actually, it is my stupidity. The 'getNextPageToken()' is a member of 'FileList list' so it is (NOW) obvious, that if I don't ask for it, I DON'T GET IT (pun intended).